# Graphviz: using rankdir in subgraph?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'd like to use TB rankdir for my top-level graph, but LR rankdir within subgraphs. Is this possible? The commented-out rankdir in the subgraph doesn't do anything.

```
    digraph G{
    graph [compound=true]
    subgraph "cluster_0" {
        label=top
        A->B->C
    }
    { rank=source A B C}
    
    subgraph "cluster_A" {
        label = A_zoom
        // rankdir=LR;
        A1->A2->A3->A6->A7
        A1->A4->A3->A5->A7
    }

    A->A1 [ltail="cluster_0" lhead="cluster_A"]
}
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, the **rankdir** attribute applies to the entire graph (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/rankdir/)

However, often there are graph-specific work-arounds:

- break the graph into separate pieces with different **rankdir** values, run each through **dot**, and then "glue them back together": using the **gvpack** program (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpack.1.pdf) plus **neato -n2** (https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithCoords)
- or accept a single **rankdir** value and "fake" the other **rankdir** values by using other **dot** features, like **group*,  *rank**, and/or invisible edges.  See below:

```
digraph G{
    graph [compound=true]
    rankdir=LR;
    subgraph clusterX{ // increase separation between the clusters
    subgraph "cluster_0" {
        label=top
        A->B->C
    }
    peripheries=0 // hide this cluster, placed at end to prevent inheritance
    }
    //{ rank=source A B C}
    
    subgraph "cluster_A" {
        label = A_zoom
        // rankdir=LR;
        A1->A2->A3->A6->A7
        A1->A4->A3->A5->A7
    }

    //A->A1 [ltail="cluster_0" lhead="cluster_A"]
    A->A2 [ltail="cluster_0" lhead="cluster_A"]    
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thanks - this looks exactly like I want it to! But how could we know that 'top' would come out on top of 'A_zoom'? Might it as well have been placed to the side?

Comment: Probably not on the side because A->A2 is one rank difference.  "Top" cluster is placed above "zoom" seemingly because it it appears 1st in the input file.  Not very satisfying, but there you go.